Understanding それを見越した
From Kokoro chapter 6,

しかしその私だけにはこの直感が後になって事実の上に証拠立てられたのだから、私は若々しいといわれても、馬鹿げていると笑われても、それを見越した自分の直覚をとにかく頼もしくまた嬉しく思っている。

In それを見越した, それ refers to 若々しいといわれるのと馬鹿げていると笑われてるの, right? In this case, does 見越す here means to anticipate or to look past?
Also, it might be out of scope for this question but I don't get the logic operates in this sentence. The narrator is saying that since his instincts got vindicated, he thinks it is something that can be relied on and is happy with it? What the narrator is trying to say?

No, それ refers to この直感, which in turn refers to どうしても(先生に)近づかなければいられないという感じ mentioned earlier in the paragraph.

私は最初から先生には近づきがたい不思議があるように思っていた。それでいて、どうしても近づかなければいられないという感じが、どこかに強く働いた。こういう感じを先生に対してもっていたものは、多くの人のうちであるいは私だけかも知れない。しかしその私だけにはこの直感が後になって事実の上に証拠立てられたのだから、私は若々しいといわれても、馬鹿げていると笑われても、それを見越した自分の直覚をとにかく頼もしくまた嬉しく思っている。

The phrases in bold refer to the same thing. And the last sentence means:

But at least for me, this hunch was later proven true by facts, so even if I'm called young or laughed at for being foolish, I (still) feel proud and happy about my intuition to foresee it.


Thanks. So it is saying that the narrator initially didn't know the feeling he has for sensei and he thought that he wanted to become close with him, which turned out to be true.

@weeab00 That's not accurate. The narrator somehow strongly felt he has to become close with sensei. But he didn't know whether it was merely an illusion or a truly intuitive foresight, until much later.
